# Как подключить sitemap.xml на PHP с помощью include?

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

У меня есть sitemap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset
  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"><url<loc>http://site.ru/</loc></url><url><loc>http://site.ru/filmebi.php</loc</url><url><loc>http://site.ru/musika.php</loc>
```

и на PHP коде где у меня такой код:

```
switch($Page){
    case "index":
       include_once('resource/main.php');
    break;
    case "aboutus":
       include_once('resource/about.php');
    break;
    case "ads":
       include_once('resource/ads.php');
    break;
    case "news":
       include_once('resource/news.php');
    break;
    case "sitemap.xml":  //тут у меня проблема
       include_once('sitemap.xml' ); 
    break;
    case "robots.txt":
       include_once('robots.txt');
    break;   default:
      include_once('error/error404.php');
```

указываю `include_once('sitemap.xml' );` но пишет такую ошибку :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\OpenServer\domains\testi.dev\sitemap.xml on line 1
```

Что мне делать?

Comment: Непонятно, почему заголовок был "как создать файл", а сам вопрос про то как вывести уже существующий файл.

Answer (score 1):

Команда include служит для включения **PHP кода**.
Файл sitemap.xml РНР кодом не является.
Следовательно, команду include для этого файла применять не следует.

> что мне делать?

Дать на этот файл прямую ссылку.

Comment: Тогда какую команду исползовать?

Comment: Никакую. Зачем вообще отдавать этот файл через РНР? Этот файл надо отдавать по прямой ссылке. БЕЗ РНР

Comment: у меня default в switch , и даже когда я удаляю default все равно не переходит прямо на ссылку site.ru/sitemap.xml проста белый экран

Comment: Не нужно никакого default. Не нужно никакого switch. Не нужно никакого PHP. Надо просто обратиться к файлу, напрямую: `http://site.ru/sitemap.xml`, БЕЗ РНР

Answer (score 1):

Проблема у Вас в том, что вы в PHP код пытаетесь подключить XML файл, а интерпретатор пытается его обработать, поэтому вы получаете ошибку.

Для получения содержимого файла в какую-то либо переменую воспользуйтесь функцией file_get_contents, после чего делайте его вывод на экран. Если есть необходимость в его обработке и произведении каких-то действий над ним.

Comment: Остается вопрос, ЗАЧЕМ получать этот файл в переменную и затем выводить её на экран.

Comment: Я для начала подумал, что пользователь захочет получать данный файл и возможно производить над ним какие-то действия. Естественно, если нет необходимости в его обработке, то это просто лишняя трата процессорного времени.